# How can I get the notificationKey for the group by its name?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I created a group in FCM with name `foo`, it returns a notification key `xasxaessqerefdc` for the group `foo`. Is there any API provided by FCM to find the notification key for the group using its group name.

Comment: @AL is there any way to delete the group without knowing the notificationKey

Comment: Nope. A group gets deleted if there are no more tokens in it, and in order to remove a token, you need to have the `notification_key`.